# Visual Studio 2013 Syntax Highlighting Stops Working

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, syntax-highlighting

I am using Visual C++ for a game project that I'm building.

I noticed that whenever I scroll down, always when editing a HEADER file, color coding in Visual Studio 2013, stops working, and is restored only by using CTRL + S.

I've tried deleting the .suo file, restoring all VC settings, restarting it, restarting the PC, and loading the solution again...

Could you help me pinpoint the problem?

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid my experience is that anything involving C++ intellisense in VS is...quirky at best.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Updating VS, nothing happened.

However, I have been using define guards (#ifndef x #define x #endif) in all my headers, and it finally turns out that that's what caused the problem... However, I don't see why...

Is there any way to prevent this?

**EDIT** #pragma once works.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2012 had the same issue and as far as I'm aware, there's nothing to do about it. Just CTRL-S when it does that. Deleting the intellisense database (.sdf) might also help when CTRL-S doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Yeah, I just deleted the DB... Nothing Happened... Isn't this supposed to be a serious bug for them to fix ?!

Comment: I just noticed it only color codes, code that is inside the editor viewport... Maybe that's somehow related to the issue...